# Reusable Custom Symfony FormType

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a custom Symfony FormType which helps to parse date from a string. (Project is available on my Github https://github.com/ThBM/date-text-type)

In order to be able to use this class again in other Symfony projects, I would like to wrap it into a composer package.

I tried to do the same as a Standard library but I have the following error when I run my Symfony app :  Too few arguments to function DateTextType::__constuct.

It seems like Dependency Injection is not working : DateStringParserTransform is not injected in the DateTextType construtor when I build my form.
Do you have any lead on how to properly package a Custome Symfony Component?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There may be a problem with the namespace. Try changing it to `Symfony\Component\DataTextType`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

DataTransformer should not be injected in the custom FormType. You could just use an instance of it in the buildForm function.

```
<?php 
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder->addModelTransformer(new DateStringParserTransform());
}
```

I also follow this link in order to structure my package as a Symfony bundle. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.